# PagedListHolder search by keyword without using DAO

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-3, pagedlist

I am actually using Spring 3 MVC and listing data with pagination using `PagedListHolder` passing the method from my service layer to get all rows from a DB table like this:

```
PagedListHolder myList = new PagedListHolder(myService.getAll());
```

**And this is my controller code:**

```
public class MyListController implements Controller {

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String page = request.getParameter("page");

        MyService myService = new MyService();
        PagedListHolder myList = new PagedListHolder(myService.getAll());
        myList.setPageSize(5); 

        if ("next".equals(page)) {
            myList.nextPage();
        }
        else if ("previous".equals(page)) {
            myList.previousPage();
        }

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("myList");
        modelAndView.addObject("myList", myList.getPageList());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

So, this is working perfect but I want to make now a search from `myList`by using a keyword and the normal way I think could be implementing a method in `DAO` and `Service` layers like for example:

```
...
String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");
PagedListHolder myList = new PagedListHolder(myService.findByWord(keyword));
...
```

At this point `myList` will return all rows from DB that matches my keyword.

What I want to know is if there is a way to search from `myList` (using `myService.getAll();` method and maybe some other method from `PagedListHolder`) and avoid modifying the `DAO` and `Service` layers for not creating extra methods like the one I used in the example above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no search method in `PagedListHolder`. You can check the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring/2.5.5/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.java).

In addition, if you are using Maven and STS(or maybe also Eclipse), you can check the code by **Open Type** command. Shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, well... I know how to do that but sometimes i dont understand the description of a method and also there is no extra information and no reference at google